# Getting unknown domain when ping-ing to my website hosted in VPS

Tags: linux, networking, vps

I'm running a website on a VPS, everything has been going good but I noticed unknown domain when I ping my website.

```
64 bytes from blockchain.myvenus.ooo (serverip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=429 ms
64 bytes from blockchain.myvenus.ooo (serverip): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=614 ms
64 bytes from blockchain.myvenus.ooo (serverip): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=637 ms
64 bytes from blockchain.myvenus.ooo (serverip): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=225 ms
```

Obviously this is a bit concerning, I've never put any blockchain related program on my server let alone considering it, it's a production server where I also put my client data etc.

Is this normal? Should I be worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll just be your [*reverse DNS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) record. Assuming this is doing a full recursive lookup, it's just the record set by the owner of that IP address, your hosting provider. Possibly left over from a previous customer.

You'll need to either go through your hosting provider's control panel or contact them to update those records.